# A question concerning the functional of a functional of the former functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations, quantum-field-theory, frechet-derivative

Let $\varphi(x)$ and $j(x)$ be two field configurations. Let $\Gamma[\varphi]$ be a functional of the field $\varphi$ defined by:

$$ \Gamma[\varphi] := \sup_j \ F[\varphi, j] = F[\varphi, j_\varphi] $$

where $F[\varphi, j]$ is a functional of both $\varphi$ and $j$, and for any fixed $\varphi$, the unique field configuration that extremizes $F$ is $j_\varphi$, which is to say,

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta j} F[\varphi,j] \Big\rvert_{j=j_\varphi} = 0 \,.$$

Now suppose that the structure of $F$ allows the following identity to hold:

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi} \Gamma[\varphi] + j_\varphi = 0 \,.$$

Please keep in mind that the above equality is an *identity*, but it can be easily promoted to the status of an *equation* as follows:

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi} \Gamma[\varphi] + j = 0 \,,$$

whose solution is, of course, $j=j_\varphi$ for any given $\varphi$. Alternatively, however, we can fix $j$ and ask for the $\varphi =: \varphi_j$ that solves it.

We then have an *equivalent identity*:

$$  \frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi} \Gamma[\varphi]\Big|_{\varphi=\varphi_j} + j = 0 \,. $$

In such a scenario, would it be true to say that

$$ \Gamma[\varphi_j] = F[\varphi_j, j] $$

which allows us to write a functional of $j$ instead of $\varphi$? If yes, can you please provide a justification for the above claim?

Note that it is equivalent to claiming that $$ j_{\varphi_j} = j \,.$$

What does that even mean?

Thank you very much for your time!

---

[`Motivation: Effective Quantum Action`]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so.  Here's a possible justification.  To avoid confusion with our fixed $j$, I will denote $J_\varphi$ as the solution $k$ of $\frac{\delta}{\delta k}F[\varphi,k]=0$.  Now, by definition of $J_{\varphi_j}$ and the structure identity of $F$, we have 
$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma[\varphi_j]+J_{\varphi_j}=0.
$$
By definition of $\varphi_j$, we have
$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma[\varphi]|_{\varphi=\varphi_j}+j=0.
$$
But $\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma[\varphi_j]\equiv \frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma[\varphi]|_{\varphi=\varphi_j}$ is the same thing in two different notations, so we get $J_{\varphi_j}=j$.

Comment: You are right. But there is a small notational problem.  You see $\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma[\varphi_j] = 0$ because $\varphi_j$ is a fixed field configuration. It's like saying $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\big(f(2)\big) = 0.$ However, your argument still holds because the structure identity reads: $\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi_j}\Gamma[\varphi_j]+J_{\varphi_j}=0$ and $\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi_j}\Gamma[\varphi_j] \equiv \frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma[\varphi]|_{\varphi=\varphi_j}.$

Comment: I see, I was interpreting $\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma[\varphi_j]$ as $\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi}\Gamma\right)[\varphi_j]$, analogously to $\frac{df}{dx}(2)=\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)(2)$.  But I believe we mean the same thing!